# Trying to install a ruby gem on Mac OSX gives me an error: "Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I've been trying to install mongrel on my Mac OS X (Leopard) and it errors out with the message "Failed to build em native extension".

What am I missing in my system? The versions of Ruby and gems that I am using are 1.8.7 and 1.3.3 respectively.

Comment: Can you please include the full trace?

Answer (score 1):

you need to have XCode installed. you can get that from your OSX installation DVD or from apple's website. i would get the latest version from the website, rather than the one from your dvd.